# drop index with a comma in the name

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1091

I have a table (well there are a bunch of them) with an index that contains a comma

```
....
FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description,title` (`description`,`title`), -- <-- HERE
  FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content,title` (`content`,`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=150296 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I am moving to InnoDB + sphinx so want to drop all the FULLTEXT indexes and these are proving to be a problem.

Quotes:

```
DROP INDEX 'content,title' ON `table`
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP INDEX 'content,title'
```

Backticks:
    DROP INDEX `content,title` ON `table`
    ALTER TABLE `table` DROP INDEX `content,title`

Escaped:
    ALTER TABLE `articles` DROP INDEX `description\,title`

Various forms of escaping, also tried using LIKE with wild chars.

Actual error: `Can't DROP 'description,title'; check that column/key exists`

@CodeBird

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_NAME='articles' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test' AND INDEX_NAME LIKE 'descri%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
 TABLE_SCHEMA: test
   TABLE_NAME: articles
   NON_UNIQUE: 1
 INDEX_SCHEMA: test
   INDEX_NAME: description,title
 SEQ_IN_INDEX: 1
  COLUMN_NAME: description
    COLLATION: NULL
  CARDINALITY: NULL
     SUB_PART: NULL
       PACKED: NULL
     NULLABLE: YES
   INDEX_TYPE: FULLTEXT
      COMMENT:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
 TABLE_SCHEMA: test
   TABLE_NAME: articles
   NON_UNIQUE: 1
 INDEX_SCHEMA: test
   INDEX_NAME: description,title
 SEQ_IN_INDEX: 2
  COLUMN_NAME: title
    COLLATION: NULL
  CARDINALITY: NULL
     SUB_PART: NULL
       PACKED: NULL
     NULLABLE: YES
   INDEX_TYPE: FULLTEXT
      COMMENT:
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. How about `DROP INDEX 'content\,title' ON `table``

Comment: If all else fails, can't you create a new table the way you want it, export the data from the old in to the new, drop the old, and then rename the new to the old name?

Comment: @PatrickQ there are many tables, and 15GB DB in total, would rather find a way to drop it.

Comment: You are using quotes for the first statement use back ticks.

Comment: try selecting the indexes of this table from information_schema, maybe it gives you a clue `SELECT INDEX_NAME
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name'`

Comment: Suggestion: Try to rename the index name stored into system table

Comment: @Mihai Read the question again, I have tried both...

Comment: `ALTER TABLE … DROP … ` with backticks seem to work for me.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af5602  (no error when you build the schema). Also, note that my previous comment did say "if all else fails" ;) It's up to you to determine when you should cut your losses trying to do it this way.

Comment: I don't see why a comma would cause an issue especially surrounded by backticks, just try to select your indexes and check what is really happening.

Comment: @CodeBird see update for select from info schema

Comment: `UPDATE information_schema.STATISTICS SET INDEX_NAME='to_be_dropped' WHERE TABLE_NAME='articles' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test' AND INDEX_NAME LIKE 'descri%'\G` can you try this if you have root access?

Comment: @CodeBird nice one, that will do. make an answer and its accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having root access you should be able to update your index name in information_schema then try dropping them:

```
UPDATE information_schema.STATISTICS SET INDEX_NAME='to_be_dropped' 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='articles' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test' 
AND INDEX_NAME LIKE 'descri%'
```

Comment: I have not figured out what is required to run updates on information_schema, but this made it easy to find all the duff fields and edit manually.

Answer (score 0):

Below command should work, please check again and share if getting any error:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` DROP INDEX `content,title`;
```

You can check below sqlfiddle: First build above statement and then with above statement, it will successfully drop the index.
[fulltext index drop](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fe5d2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Table and column names must be quoted with backticks, but you're using single quotes.  (You're using backticks correctly everywhere else).

Change:

```
DROP INDEX 'content,title' ON `table`;
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP INDEX 'content,title';
```

To:

```
DROP INDEX `content,title` ON `table`;
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP INDEX `content,title`;
```

Also, I suggest you not use table/column/index names that need to be quoted, because it's a hassle and error-prone, as you've seen.  An index name of `content_title` instead of `content,title` would have saved you this trouble.

Comment: As I said in the question, I have tried both quoted and backticked, both no dice. Also this is a DB that was created 10 years before I started on it ;)